# How to filter only one datagrid which has same Itemssource as another datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

First datagrid is binded to ObservableCollection from my MainViewModel class. Second datagrid which i want to filter is binded like this:

```
        ICollectionView icv;
        icv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(list1);
        icv.Filter = FilterTable;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = icv;
```

list1 is same ObservableCollection from first datagrid. With this code my both datagrids were filtered. Is there any way to filter only second datagrid, but not first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two different view and get this filter done. refer below code.

```
 <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsViews}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >            
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsFileterViews}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>       
</StackPanel>
class MainViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> perList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList 
    {
        get { return perList; }
        set { perList = value; }
    }
    public ICollectionView PersonsViews { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView PersonsFileterViews { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 1, Name = "Test1"});
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 2, Name = "Test2" });
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 3, Name = "Test3" });
        perList.Add(new Person() { Age = 4, Name = "Test4" });

        PersonsViews = new CollectionViewSource { Source = PersonList }.View;
        PersonsFileterViews = new CollectionViewSource { Source = PersonList }.View;
        PersonsFileterViews.Filter = new Predicate<object>(x => ((Person)x).Age > 2);            
    }     

}


public class Person
{
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }


}
```

Comment: Tnx, i did it with only one View, but your code helped me a lot.